# Who is the woman in the intro of Outer Limits?

Tags: the-outer-limits

The question is the following: who is the woman in the intro of *The Outer Limits*?

I found [this FAQ on an *Outer Limits* fansite](http://www.innermind.com/outerlimits/misc/olfaq.htm#OLFAQG), but no answer:

> *Who is the woman in some versions of the NOL opening credits?*
>
> Over the years lots of people have asked about this. Unfortunately I have not found anyone who knows. If anyone can answer this please inform me so I can pass it on.

[image]

Comment: More stills of the woman here: http://www.innermind.com/outerlimits/pictures/n_pits00/n_pits00.htm

Comment: ...and the intro can be seen on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58qOHB4wJPw), although the uploader has altered the voiceover for some reason.

Comment: Jerry Uelsmann was the photographer for the main title. The images draw on his style. The girl resembles his work Symbolic Mutation (https://www.moma.org/collection/works/57346) but they are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard three answers : Diane Venora from "HEAT", Sofia Shinas from "Outer Limits : Valerie 23",  or Allysa Milano

Comment: What are your sources?

Comment: I googled it and different sites gave their sources. I could find out for sure if i knew who the creator of the opening credits( there are 3 versions)  is. There is sometmes a separate artist who makes the credits . i think the sci fi  channel showed it after HBO did. The photos are not perfect matches for any of these 3 women. The imdb did not know either.

Answer (score -2):

Sofia Shinas is the woman at the beginning of the OL episodes in the apple core.

Comment: How do you know? Please add a source or some kind of justification to this answer - thanks.

Comment: Sofia Shinas starred in two episodes of *The Outer Limits* as an actual character.  Also, Shinas looks nothing like the woman in the intro sequence.  Are you sure you're not getting confused?